# Detecting and storing logout times

Tags: php, session, logging, tracking, logout

My application currently stores some basic _SESSION events, such as login and each page/URI requested.  I've been asked to enhance event logging to include tracking when users log out.

The trouble with logouts is that users don't always remember to click a dedicated Logout button.  Sometimes they just leave the browser open, or close the open browser windows, or simply shut down.  I can't always be guaranteed an exact logout event.

I can get a rough idea of user logout times by querying my event table for periods of no activity, however this seems roughshod.

Is there a best practice for detecting passive logouts in PHP?

Comment: I would piggyback on the session TTL.  Are you using a database table or file system?  Don't think you can really hook into the session GC so would probably just want to poll the sessions.

Comment: Client sends heartbeat to server each one minute. If client closes browser, there is no heartbeat any longer.

Comment: The answer is in your question. Use the user's last activity timestamp including your set period of inactivity (ie with a cronjob) - there's really no good method to rely on client input in this specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have your answer - no activity means they have logged out.

If your server can handle it, and it's really important, you can set a Javascript timeout to "ping"every minute. If you get the ping, then the browser is still on the page, if you don't, they have probably moved on. Exactly when you define "logout" though is still a little bit of guess work, add the user may leave the page then return later while the session is valid.

Comment: "and the user may leave the page then return later while the session is valid."  Which is why I think maybe watching for session files going away is a better approach.  If using database for storage a trigger could be a good way to leverage PHP's session management.  I mean what better way to define 'logged in' than them being technically logged in.

Comment: Totally agree. It's just that the OP is asking for a more precise way of saying when they closed the browser - and this is the only feasible option (other than opening sockets and monitoring that way, but they are not supported enough in browsers to even consider it).

Comment: My users will almost never browse away from the application, and I do like the immediacy of the "ping" or "hearbeat" approach.  It sounds like the less accurate but better way is to monitor the session folder for triggering a logout event.    Thanks both for the responses.